# The set of all positive values of $a$ for which $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac 1n - \tan^{-1}(\frac 1n)\right) ^{3a}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The set of all positive values of $a$ for which the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac 1n - \tan^{-1}(\frac 1n) \right) ^{3a}$ converges is
(a) $(0,\frac 13]$

(b) $(0,\frac 13)$

(c) $[\frac 13,\infty)$

(d) $(\frac 13, \infty)$

$\bf{Try}:$

If we choose $a=\frac 13$ then $\left( \frac 1n - \tan^{-1}(\frac 1n) \right) =\frac 1n - \{ \frac 1n - \frac 1{3n^3}+\frac 1{5n^5}-\cdots\}=\frac 1{3n^3}-\frac 1{5n^5}+\cdots$. Which is convergent. Hence option (b) and (d) are false. I'm unable to go further. I also want to know if a direct proof is possible without choosing $a$.

Comment: I think it should be: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac 1n - \arctan\left(\frac 1n\right) \right) ^{3a} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)^{3a} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty O\left(\frac{1}{n^{9a}}\right)$$
Therefore, the series converges when $9a > 1 \iff a > 1/9$

Comment: But no option shows that. So the options are wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{1}{n}-tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{n})\approx \frac{1}{3n^3}$for large $n$.  Therefore sum converges for $a\gt \frac{1}{9}$

Comment: But none of the option gives that

Comment: @Math-Learner You are right.  All the options available are wrong.   I guess it was supposed to be $a$ not $3a$ for the exponent.